# How long are Spotlight items (CSSearchableItem) persisted?

Tags: ios, objective-c, spotlight

If I manually index a `CSSearchableItem` in my application, is it going to be indexed forever? Or will Spotlight remove it from its index after a while (how long?)?

If it is removed after a while, is it possible to mark it as "persistent"?

Answer (score 3):

The inline documentation for `CSSearchableItem` states that the `expirationDate` will default to one month

[image]

I don't see this in Apple's documentation, however.

Answer (score 1):

[According to Paul Hudson](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/32/4/how-to-add-core-spotlight-to-index-your-app-content), each `CSSearchableItem` will expire after one month. If you want to keep your items around, you should set `<yourItem>.expirationDate` to some date in the distant future

Answer (score -3):

CSSearchableItem should persist for as long as your app is there installed on the device.

Comment: Thanks! Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: This is not true - see the answer above